# Finding "orphan" routes, etc, in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

We're at a point in our development where there have been many different fingers in our Rails pie, and there are things we *know* exist currently that are not being used, etc. What I'm looking for is some way of programmatically determining if there are any orphan routes in the controllers, maybe something that will take the output of rails routes and see if there is anything extraneous in the code. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what your looking for is known as code metrics, there's one solutions in particular that I can think of that sort of covers what you need. It's known as the [rails_best_practices](https://github.com/railsbp/rails_best_practices) gem, one of the many things it checks for is unused controller actions. In addition it will inform you that auto generated routes (e.g., index, show, edit, update, etc..) require restricting when not all of them are used.

For instance the following line will create seven RESTful routes for your `Foo` controller, regardless of whether they're actually ever implemented or not:

```
resources :foo
```

But if your controller only makes use of say the index, show, new, create actions it will tell you to add the `:only` directive to your route mapping for those actions.

There might be some additional options out there that are more inline with what you need, I recommend taking a look at the Ruby Toolbox's code metrics category and seeing what's out there. Here's the link: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/code_metrics